# How to add new columns to show last value (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I've edited the table and added more info. Hopeful this will give a better picture to my question

I have a df which i'd like to add a new columns (last1, last2, last3, etc...) showing its last value.

CR1, CR2, CR3, etc.. represents the current percentile of the persons' rank; last1, last2, last3, etc represent the last percentile of the persons' rank

i think the easiest way to explain my question is; How to create new columns that shows the value from the last column.
example: on 1st Aug : Mary, column last1, last2, last3, should show 33%, 33%, 33%. Which are value of CR1, CR2, CR2 of 1st Jun : Mary

Here's the code for the df

```py
data = {'Date':['1-Jan', '1-Jan', '1-Jan', '1-Jan',
'1-Mar', '1-Mar', '1-Mar', '1-Mar',
'1-Jun', '1-Jun', '1-Jun', '1-Jun', '1-Jun',
'1-July', '1-July', '1-July',
'1-Aug', '1-Aug', '1-Aug', '1-Aug', '1-Aug', '1-Aug'],
'Name':['Pete', 'Mary', 'John', 'Frank',
'Mary', 'John', 'Frank', 'Pete',
'Pete', 'John', 'Mary', 'Frank' 'Mary',
'Luke', 'Cindy', 'Joe',
'Luke', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Tang', 'Mary', 'Tang'],
'ClassRank':[1, 2, 3, 4,
1, 2, 3, 4,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
1, 2, 3,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(df)
```

```py
df['add'] = (df.groupby(['ClassRank', 'Name']).cumcount() + 1)
df['all'] = (df.groupby('Name')['ClassRank'].cumcount() + 1)
df['1'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 1]
df['2'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 2]
df['3'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 3]
df['4'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 4]
df['5'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 5]
df['6'] = df['add'].loc[df.ClassRank == 6]

df = df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0))
df['CR1'] = (df['1'] / df['all']) * 100
df['CR2'] = (df['2'] / df['all']) * 100
df['CR3'] = (df['3'] / df['all']) * 100
df['CR4'] = (df['4'] / df['all']) * 100
df['CR5'] = (df['5'] / df['all']) * 100
df['CR6'] = (df['6'] / df['all']) * 100

df = df.drop(['add', 'all', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], axis=1).round(2)
```

Original Output

[image]

Output required(in bold): last1, last2, last3, last4, last5, etc... added

[image]

Kindly note that since there is no data available before 1-Jan, therefore, the last value (last1, last2, last3, etc) should reflect 0% as shown in the above example.

Comment: Do you want shift columns `CR` by `4` rows?

Comment: The actual df has over 100k rows with thousand of unique names which are not in sequence. In addition, the ranks are not only 1 to 4, there are 1 to 6, 1 to 8, 1 to 10, etc.Therefore, shifting columns by a specific numbers of rows won’t work here.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what are Last columns? Because not clear from question.

Comment: it seems there are last values of groups date? because it seems there is shift of groups only

Comment: Yes, the last1, last2, last3, last4 columns are the last values of the groups which I need.  Sorry I wasn’t clear with my question. And as mentioned, because the actual df classranks are not only 1 to 4, therefore, shift columns a specific numbers of rows won’t work.

Comment: Will adding another table with different number of class rank (example: 1-7) make my question clearer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203982/discussion-between-jezrael-and-manonthemoon).